# Config Laradock with Nginx HHVM and MongoDB

Tags: laravel, mongodb, docker, hhvm, laradock

How can I config [Laradock](http://laradock.io/) to run project with `Nginx`, `HHVM` and `MongoDB`?

I edit my `.env` file and change `PHP_INTERPRETER` from `php-fpm` to `hhvm` but nothing happens and the project still runs with `php-fpm`.

**Here is part of my .env file:**

```
...
PHP_INTERPRETER=hhvm
...
### NGINX ##############################################################################################################

NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT=80
NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT=443
NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH=./logs/nginx/
NGINX_SITES_PATH=./nginx/sites/
NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=hhvm
NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=9000
...
```

Comment: Have you rebuilt the images or just rerunning the old ones?

Comment: @btl i am rebuilding

Comment: Check the container ID between builds and verify you're not getting a cached image. Maybe even `docker system prune` to be sure, unless you have important data stored.

Comment: @btl should i run this command first time : `docker-compose up -d nginx mongo hhvm` ?

Comment: Try `docker-compose build --no-cache nginx mongo hhvm ` first.

Comment: @btl why no cache?

Comment: So it will build a fresh image. It's possible you have old layers being reused and could be why it's not reflecting the changes.

Answer (score 0):

edit laradock/hhvm/Dockerfile

Add user options

```
USER www-data
CMD ["/usr/bin/hhvm", "--user", "www-data", "-m", "server", "-c", "/etc/hhvm/server.ini"]
```

the whole file will like

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"

RUN apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x5a16e7281be7a449

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common wget \
    && wget -O - http://dl.hhvm.com/conf/hhvm.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add - \
    && add-apt-repository "deb http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y hhvm \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /var/www

COPY server.ini /etc/hhvm/server.ini

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

WORKDIR /var/www

USER www-data

CMD ["/usr/bin/hhvm", "--user", "www-data", "-m", "server", "-c", "/etc/hhvm/server.ini"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

then rebuild hhvm, it works for me